# Calculating the area covered by the objects of irregular shapes in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project where I'm estimating the wheat yield based on the wheat spikes in the image. After detecting spikes using Faster-RCNN and color based segmentation, the following is the resultant image where there are only spikes in the image.

[image: Image having Wheat spikes only]

Now my goal is to estimate the yield produced by the spikes in the image using python. For this, we may have to calculate the area covered by the objects of polygon shapes or we may have to work around the pixel values to calculate the area. But I don't know how we can do this. Please Let me know If anyone has the solution. Thanks

Comment: Simply make a black and white mask image by cv2.threshold or cv2.inRange. The the total number of pixels that are white will be the average value of the mask times the width times the height. Number of white pixels  = Average * Width * Height. See cv2.mean() for the average.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? or provide sample code?

Comment: @fmw42 "Then the total number of pixels that are white will be the average value of the mask times the width times the height." What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: Get the average of the binary mask image, which will be one single value. Then multiply that by the Width of the image and then by the Height of the image. Round the result. That result will be equal to the total number of white pixels in the mask and thus the total pixels that are not black (i.e. are colored) in your image.

Comment: Well, that would return the number of white pixels actually. So, how can we use that to estimate the value in terms of area or estimate the yield?

Comment: The number of white pixels is the area (in pixels) converted by the white pixels.

Comment: if we know the area covered in the image, then can we convert it to actual area(not in pixels)?

Comment: You would need a scale factor between pixels and ground area in inches or feet.

Comment: yeah, that exactly what I want to work on. I do have the size of the area covered in the image and I want to find the area covered by the spikes. So, I can get the area in terms of some measurement unit. Any lead in this would be really kind of you. Thanks

Comment: Area of white pixels in square ft = mask average * area of image in square ft

Comment: Possible approaches are to 1) find contours and sum the area with `cv2.contourArea()` or 2) use `cv2.countNonZero()` to grab all desired pixels then use it to calculate area

Comment: @nathancy I know it will help me in getting all the spikes pixel but my main goal is to estimate the yield. So, I may be required to find the area cover by those spikes and once the area is found how I'll get the yield produced by those spikes? I'm looking  forward to your answer. Thanks

Comment: @FaizanKhan, take a look at fmw42's great solution. My answer would have been similar to his approach of counting non zero pixels in the thresholded image.   The result of the solution tells us the area and ratio of the image covered by the spikes, to estimate the yield, you need to physically determine the calibrated weight ratio yourself. Unfortunately the image itself is unable to tell us the weight of the spikes or provide any other measurement properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area in pixels of the image that are not black can be found from creating a binary mask. The area in pixels is equal to the total number of white pixels in the mask. One way to get that is to compute the fraction of white pixels in the image. The number of white pixels will then be the fraction * width * height of the image. The fraction is just the average of the image divided by the maximum possible gray level (255). So

area in pixels of white pixels = (average/255)*width*height

Thus, get the fractional average (average/255) of the binary mask image (by thresholding at 0). The result for the average will be one single value. Then multiply that by the Width of the image and then by the Height of the image. That result will be equal to the total number of white pixels in the mask and thus the total pixels that are not black (i.e. are colored) in your image. The number of white pixels is the pixel area of the non-black pixels in your image.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("Mask", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
ave = cv2.mean(thresh)[0]/255
print(ave)
0.310184375
area = ave*height*width
print(area)
198518.0
```

Note that this is the non-black pixel area. Some of your rectangles have black inside them. So this is not the area of the rectangle. You would have ensure that your image had no black pixels before isolating the rectangles to get the area of the rectangles.

**ADDITION**

A simpler approach, suggested by Mark Setchell, is to simply count the number of nonzero pixels in the thresholded image. It computes the same number as above.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("Mask", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
area2 = cv2.countNonZero(thresh)
print(area2)
198518
```

**ADDITION 2**

If you know the ground area or dimensions in meters (0.8 m on  aside as per your comment) corresponding to the area covered by the image, then the ground area corresponding to the count of non-zero pixels will be:

```
area on ground for nonzero pixels = count * 0.8 * 0.8 / (width * height)
```

where width and height are the pixel dimensions of the image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("Mask", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
count = cv2.countNonZero(thresh)
area = count*0.8*0.8/(width*height)
print(area)
0.19851800000000003
```

So the result is 0.198518 square meters

Comment: That's fine but my main aim is to calculate the area in terms of some measurement unit. So, I can estimate the yield based on that. I do have the area covered in the image. Thanks

Comment: See my comments below the question. Just multiply the mask average by the area in square ft for the full image. Please tell us what the area of the image is in square ft or square inches or the like.

Comment: I'll try that and will let you know then. Thanks for your time and cooperation

Comment: CORRECTION: In OpeCV the average will be less than 255. So you have to divide by 255 to get the fractional average. See modified code in my answer that reflects this.

Comment: Mark Setchell (private email) suggests using cv2.countNonZero(), which of course is much simpler than my method (which was how I would have handled it in ImageMagick). I have added that to my post above.

Comment: 0.8 m × 0.8 m is the region area

Comment: See my ADDITION 2 in my answer where `area = count * 0.8 * 0.8 / (width * height)`

Comment: Ok but the final goal it to estimate the yield. So, how can I use the area to get the yield produced by the spikes in the image?

Comment: The area I compute in ADDITION 2 is includes only the area covered by non-black pixels. Black pixels inside the rectangles are excluded. Those black pixels are not part of the vegetation, but are holes between leaves. So they should not count and are excluded by my computation. Thus, if I understand your problem, my answer is correct for the yield. If I do not understand, please define "yield".

Comment: well, your solution gives me the area actually but yield means the grain in some unit like gram and kg, etc. How can we use that calculated area to get the yield produced by the spikes

Comment: You need to multiply the area by kg/area. You will have to compute that from physical measurements of your actual leaves. Take some number of plant leaves and measure the surface area and the weight and get the ratio of weight to area. This is beyond the scope of this forum.

Comment: Ain't there any way through which we can estimate the yield based on the area covered by the spikes

Comment: NO! Not without knowing the kg/area. Images have no way to know how much your vegetation weighs.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

1. Loads the image in grayscale `(0[Black] - 255[White])`
2. Extract pixels above certain level. I have for more than `60` using `cv2.threshold`
3. Fill in small white blobs using smallest kernel `(3,3)` using `cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)`
4. Extract the contours from threshold image
5. Iterate through each contour in reverse order(right top to bottom right corner)
6. As you iterate through the each contour calculate its properties

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('RIUXF.jpg',0)
hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

# Area occupied by black region
black_area = np.true_divide(hist[0],np.prod(img.shape))[0]*100

# extract no black parts
thresh = cv2.threshold(img,60,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)

# fill in the small white spots
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# extract the contours
contours = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

blank_image = np.zeros((img.shape),np.uint8)
image_area = np.prod(img.shape)

# iterate through the contours detected from right top corner
for i,c in enumerate(contours[::-1]):

    # turn blank_image black
    blank_image *= 0

    # draw filled contour
    cv2.drawContours(blank_image, [c], 0, (255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)

    contour_area = cv2.contourArea(c)

    # percentage of area contour
    contour_area_pc = np.true_divide(int(contour_area),image_area)*100 if int(contour_area) > 1  else 0 
    text = ' '.join(['Contour:',str(i),'Area:',str(round(contour_area,2)),'Percentage Area:',str(round(contour_area_pc,2))])
    cv2.putText(blank_image,text,(10,60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,(255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
    
    plt.imshow(blank_image, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
    plt.show()
```

Sample output

[image]

PS: I doubt if area cv2 calculates is correct