# How calculate the area of irregular object in an image (opencv)?

Tags: python, image, opencv

So I have this image:
[image]

And I need calculate area of an especific part, so I made this code:

```
# packages
from imutils import perspective
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('image1.jpg')

# load the image, convert it to grayscale, and blur it slightly
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 80, 150)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)
# find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
# sort the contours from left-to-right and initialize the
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts)
pixelsPerMetric = None
# draw the necessary contour
cv2.drawContours(image, max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea), -1, (0, 0, 255), 5)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And I obtained this image:
[image]

And I would like to measure the area (mm²) with red contourn. As reference I have the coin (572.55 mm), and other question. Is it possible measure the red and black proportion inside the red contourn. Some suggestion.

Comment: This should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830697/calculating-the-area-covered-by-the-objects-of-irregular-shapes-in-an-image

Comment: area = cv2.countNonZero(image)

Comment: There is a function [contourArea](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1) you could use. If you can threshold your red to a binary image then this is easy. Then if you want to find the proportion of the shape that is red, I would make another binary image of the original shape and then compare the areas.

Comment: This is an external question. I would like to know how did you extract the correct border of steak in very first picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go like this. Essentially:

- in the first part you will work on the external contours: you will find the coin and the slice external borders

[image: external borders]

- the coin area will help you measure the area in cm^2 of the entire slice, if you want it in mm^2 you can multiply that value by 100
- at that point you just need to quantify the lean part of the slice, which was inspired by [this great snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53989391/4092588) and `fmw42`'s great comment above

[image: lean selection]

- the fat part of the slice can be found by difference, i.e. with my values I get that `57.71%` of the slice is lean, so the remaining `42.29%` is fat
- if you don't want the entire lean part as in this snippet just calculate the area of your red contour, you seem ready to do it: keep in mind that the slice would be fatter than what I calculated here

Without further ado, here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# input image
path = "image1.jpg"
# 1 EUR coin diameter in cm
coinDiameter = 2.325
# real area for the coin in cm^2
coinArea = (coinDiameter/2)**2 * math.pi
# initializing the multiplying factor for real size
realAreaPerPixel = 1


# pixel to cm^2
def pixelToArea(objectSizeInPixel, coinSizeInPixel):
    # how many cm^2 per pixel?
    realAreaPerPixel = coinArea / coinSizeInPixel
    print("realAreaPerPixel: ", realAreaPerPixel)
    # object area in cm^2
    objectArea = realAreaPerPixel * objectSizeInPixel
    return objectArea    


# finding coin and steak contours
def getContours(img, imgContour):
    
    # find all the contours from the B&W image
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    # needed to filter only our contours of interest
    finalContours = []
    
    # for each contour found
    for cnt in contours:
        # cv2.drawContours(imgContour, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 255), 2)
        # find its area in pixel
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        print("Detected Contour with Area: ", area)

        # minimum area value is to be fixed as the one that leaves the coin as the small object on the scene
        if (area > 5000):
            perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
            
            # smaller epsilon -> more vertices detected [= more precision]
            epsilon = 0.002*perimeter
            # check how many vertices         
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, epsilon, True)
            #print(len(approx))
            
            finalContours.append([len(approx), area, approx, cnt])

    # we want only two objects here: the coin and the meat slice
    print("---\nFinal number of External Contours: ", len(finalContours))
    # so at this point finalContours should have only two elements
    # sorting in ascending order depending on the area
    finalContours = sorted(finalContours, key = lambda x:x[1], reverse=False)
    
    # drawing contours for the final objects
    for con in finalContours:
        cv2.drawContours(imgContour, con[3], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)

    return imgContour, finalContours

    
# sourcing the input image
img = cv2.imread(path)
cv2.imshow("Starting image", img)
cv2.waitKey()

# blurring
imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7, 7), 1)
# graying
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgBlur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# canny
imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgGray, 255, 195)

kernel = np.ones((2, 2))
imgDil = cv2.dilate(imgCanny, kernel, iterations = 3)
# cv2.imshow("Diluted", imgDil)
imgThre = cv2.erode(imgDil, kernel, iterations = 3)

imgFinalContours, finalContours = getContours(imgThre, img)

# first final contour has the area of the coin in pixel
coinPixelArea = finalContours[0][1]
print("Coin Area in pixel", coinPixelArea)
# second final contour has the area of the meat slice in pixel
slicePixelArea = finalContours[1][1]
print("Entire Slice Area in pixel", slicePixelArea)

# let's go cm^2
print("Coin Area in cm^2:", coinArea)
print("Entire Slice Area in cm^2:", pixelToArea(slicePixelArea, coinPixelArea))

# show  the contours on the unfiltered starting image
cv2.imshow("Final External Contours", imgFinalContours)
cv2.waitKey()


# now let's detect and quantify the lean part

# convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
# set lower and upper color limits
lowerVal = np.array([0, 159, 160])
upperVal = np.array([101, 255, 253])
# Threshold the HSV image to get only red colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lowerVal, upperVal)
# apply mask to original image - this shows the red with black blackground
final = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask= mask)

# show selection
cv2.imshow("Lean Cut", final)
cv2.waitKey()

# convert it to grayscale because countNonZero() wants 1 channel images
gray = cv2.cvtColor(final, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# cv2.imshow("Gray", gray)
# cv2.waitKey()
meatyPixelArea = cv2.countNonZero(gray)

print("Red Area in pixel: ", meatyPixelArea)
print("Red Area in cm^2: ", pixelToArea(meatyPixelArea, coinPixelArea))

# finally the body-fat ratio calculation
print("Body-Fat Ratio: ", meatyPixelArea/slicePixelArea*100, "%")

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And sorry to disturb you again. But I have a doubt. How you defined the upper and lower values for color limits?

Comment: @CuriousG. No worries. You can just pick any snippet for hsv images using trackbars and get the values from there. My goal was to select them in order to match the picture you posted with the red contour, without having the coin showing