# Calculate percentage of a circle an image fills

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I'm hoping to examine a large number of images (15K) of Byzantine Seals and calculate a score for each seal as to how fully circular (complete) it is. Sample images below.

[image: sample images]

Can anyone suggest a specific approach (or better yet, a recipe!) using Python to do this.  Been digging around documentation for CV2 and PILLOW with no luck!

Unfortunately, the answer suggested by userkk below will not tell me how much of a seal circle area is complete.  Please reopen this question.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried?

Comment: how many? are you willing to put an undergrad to work drawing circles around these things? undergrads are cheap and willing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How calculate the area of irregular object in an image (opencv - Python 3.8)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64394768/how-calculate-the-area-of-irregular-object-in-an-image-opencv-python-3-8)

Comment: Is finding the full circle and the covered semi-circle an option? It's not exactly what you asked, but knowing the circle might help you segmenting the seal?

Comment: 1: Use an edge detection algorithm such as Sobel, Scharr, or Morphological. 2: Morphological closing to fill the gaps. 3: Find largest contour. 4: Find the contour point with the largest distance from the center of the image (I am assuming you can use the center of the image as the center of the seal). 4: Compare the area of the contour to the area of a circle with the calculated radius. 5: If the shadows give you problems with edge detection, you can also try thresholding the images based on saturation in the HSV color space (maybe a value of greater than 30 or so would work).